# Java networking: how to simulate two different computers?

Tags: java, networking

I want to start network programming in Java. What's the best way to go about it in terms of testing? If I write a client and server program, I'd obviously want to test them in either a real or simulated network environment, but I only have one computer.

Am I missing something or is there a standard tool used for this?

Comment: You can install `virtual machine` if you want. With me, it isn't important, one computer is enought for starting(work with localhost ip: 127.0.0.1).

Comment: For many purposes it's ok just to stay on the same machine and run the client and server on different processes.

Comment: Simplest way is to get two different computers.  If you scrounge around you can probably find another that someone will give you.  It doesn't need to be fancy, since you can still do most of your development on your current computer.

Answer (score 1):

Use local port for both server and clients to connect to. You can simulate multiple machines easily.

Comment: It is a huge stretch to say that using "localhost" is simulating multiple machines.  (However, it is probably all that he needs at this point ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use virtual machine e.g. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot get another machine i would first get both client and servers working on the same machine and perhaps eventually use one or more vmware images to simulate things more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a virtual machine; you can create a virtual interface, that's much easier and won't eat half of your RAM.

http://www.lazysystemadmin.com/2010/05/add-virtual-interfaces-in-linux-quick.html